# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a dataframe.  Data points that are outliers will be plotted in red whereas all other outliers will be plotted in blue.

I have tried to plot the graph using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
colors = {0:'blue', 1:'red'}
plt.plot(df['Real Data'], c=df['outlier'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]))

plt.show()
```

I get the error 
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: Time Elapsed

Time elapsed is the index column of my data: [image]

Why am I getting the error? How can I correctly plot my graph without getting errors?

Comment: `plt.plot()` only accepts a single color! Is [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) what you're after?

Comment: Are you trying to `plot` or to `scatter`?